# The random number generator in numpy

Tags: numpy, ipython

I am using the `numpy.random.randn`and `numpy.random.rand`to generate random numbers. I am confusing about the difference between `random.randn` and `random.rand`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between the two is mentioned in the `docs`. Links to [Doc rand](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) and [Doc randn](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html)

For **`numpy.rand`**, you get random values generated from a uniform distribution ***within 0 - 1***

But for **`numpy.randn`** you get random values generated from a normal distribution, ***with mean 0 and variance 1.***

Just a small example.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.rand(10)
array([ 0.63067838,  0.61371053,  0.62025104,  0.42751699,  0.22862483,
        0.75287427,  0.90339087,  0.06643259,  0.17352284,  0.58213108])
>>> np.random.randn(10)
array([ 0.19972981, -0.35193746, -0.62164336,  2.22596365,  0.88984545,
       -0.28463902,  1.00123501,  1.76429108, -2.5511792 ,  0.09671888])
>>>
```

As you can see that **`rand`** gives me values ***within 0-1***,

whereas **`randn`** gives me values with **`mean == 0`** and **`variance == 1`**

To explain further, let me generate a large enough sample:

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(100)
>>> b = np.random.randn(100)
>>> np.mean(a)
0.50570149531258946
>>> np.mean(b)
-0.010864958465191673
>>>
```

you can see that the mean of **`a`** is close to `0.50`, which was generated using **`rand`**. The mean of **`b`** on the other hand is close to `0.0`, which was generated using **`randn`**

Answer (score 0):

You can *also* get a **conversion** from *rand* numbers to *randn* numbers in Python by the application of **percent point function** (ppf) for the Normal Distribution with random variables distributed ~ N(0,1). It is a well-known method of projecting any uniform random variables (0,1) onto ppf in order to get random variables for a desired cumulative distribution.

In Python we can visualize that process as follows:

```
from numpy.random import rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

u = rand(100000)   # uniformly distributed rvs
z = norm.ppf(u)    # ~ N(0,1) rvs

plt.hist(z,bins=100)
plt.show()
```

[image]